# python3.0 winrm powershell script start-process can not start process

Tags: python, powershell, winrm, start-process

use python3.10  winrm to run powershell script remotely, the start-process command can not start tsm.exe  process, is some wrong in below code? could someone help me to check this ,thank you

```
ip_item='10.12.62.23'
ps_script_tsm="""
 Start-Process  -FilePath "c:\\tmp\\tsm.exe"
"""

win = winrm.Session(ip_item, auth=('Administrator', '123456'))
r = win.run_ps(ps_script_tsm)
```

Comment: Please update your question to describe in what way, specifically, the behavior isn't the expected one, including details about error messages, if any.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.